# examples of sound+video juxtaposition

Tags: sound-design, abstract

Hi guys. Looking for a few good examples of film/CGI/games where sound and picture have completely different character, or even nothing in common, or there's any other disconnect between them, but the whole thing manages to work well. Youtube and/or links appreciated.